# Is there any way to find out total size of a collection and its items in Dspace?

Tags: postgresql, collections, size, dspace

i am trying to find out total "**size of each individual collection**" in **Dspace** for my MIS report.

Comment: any query to sum total item size of a collection in dspace

Answer (score 0):

**Use this query to get.. total collections , no of files and item size.**

select ab.TotalSize,cd.text_value,count_pdf from

(Select a.collection_id,sum(size_bytes) as TotalSize from collection2item a inner join item2bundle  b on a.item_id=b.item_id 
inner join  bundle2bitstream c on b.bundle_id=c.bundle_id inner join  bitstream d on c.bitstream_id=d.bitstream_id where  d.deleted='f'
group by a.collection_id) ab

inner join

(SELECT resource_id,count(collection2item.item_id) as count_pdf,metadatavalue.text_value FROM 
     collection2item inner join metadatavalue on 
      collection2item.collection_id=metadatavalue.resource_id where 
      metadata_field_id=64 and resource_type_id=3 GROUP BY
       metadatavalue.text_value,metadatavalue.resource_id) cd

on ab.collection_id=cd.resource_id;

Answer (score 0):

I create this query to obtain the number of items per collection and year

```
SELECT metadatavalue.resource_id AS "Colection", metadatavalue.text_value AS "Collection name", 
count(item.item_id) AS "Elements", EXTRACT(YEAR FROM item.last_modified) AS "Year" 
FROM item INNER JOIN metadatavalue ON item.owning_collection = metadatavalue.resource_id 
WHERE metadatavalue.metadata_field_id=66 AND metadatavalue.resource_type_id=3 
GROUP BY item.owning_collection, "Year", metadatavalue.resource_id, metadatavalue.text_value 
ORDER BY owning_collection
```